# Changing the pixel color in android

Tags: android

```
testButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);for (int i = 0; i < mutableBitmap.getWidth(); i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mutableBitmap.getHeight(); j++) 
                    {
                        int pixel = mutableBitmap.getPixel(i, j);
                        // get red color value
                        int red = Color.red(pixel);
                        int color = Color.argb(0xFF, red, 0, 0);
                        mutableBitmap.setPixel(i, j, color);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
                    }
                }
        }


        });
```

I am trying to change the pixel color with only red value. Therefore i get the red value from a given pixel  and then tried to replace the same pixel with only that red value. The program runs successfully but when i click the button it crashes out. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

LOGCAT error

```
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1002)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at com.example.imaging.AndroidCamera$7.onClick(AndroidCamera.java:216)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-03 15:16:57.228: E/AndroidRuntime(5103): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the error? post your logcat

Comment: I have updated with logcat errors. Something wrong went with line bitmap.setPixel(400, 200, color);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to modify pixels of a Immutable bitmap.You can not modify the pixels of a immutable Bitmap. if you try it will throw IllegalStateException.

use below method to get Mutable Bitmap from Resources

```
public static Bitmap getMutableBitmap(Resources resources,int resId) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId, options);
}
```

or use

```
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

to get mutable Bitmap from immutable bitmap

Comment: i used this line                                                   Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); the program is not showing any error also. My image is just a black screen. So when i run this program, that particular pixel should change into red color. so that a small red dot should be seen which am not able to. So how can i make sure whether its running or not

Comment: after changing pixel, are you setting this mutableBitmap to ImageView? use ImageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

Comment: i used this line..imageView.refreshDrawableState();     when i use the line that you referred..its showing error...Cannot make a static reference to a non static method

Comment: it got error free...but still cant see the change will tha change be seen if i choose to change the whole image and not jst one pixel

Comment: i chaanged the code to a loop one inoreder to change the whole image into red color.... but nothing is changed....am i doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29), you see that this method might throw an IllegalStateException if you try to set the Pixel in an immutable bitmap.

```
public void setPixel (int x, int y, int color)

Added in API level 1
Write the specified Color into the bitmap (assuming it is mutable) at the x,y coordinate. The color must be a non-premultiplied ARGB value.

Parameters
x   The x coordinate of the pixel to replace (0...width-1)
y   The y coordinate of the pixel to replace (0...height-1)
color   The ARGB color to write into the bitmap
Throws
IllegalStateException   if the bitmap is not mutable
IllegalArgumentException    if x, y are outside of the bitmap's bounds.
```

If you are using one of those `createBitmap` methods, most of them return immutable bitmaps, so either use a different creator method, or get a mutable copy of the bitmap you get.

Comment: i wass too reading this documentation...so here i need to change the immutable bitmap to mutable right?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29) to create the immutable bitmap...

```
testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Config config = null;
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            if (bitmap.getConfig() == null) {
                config = Config.ARGB_8888;
            } else {
                config = bitmap.getConfig();
            }
            int pixel;
            // Here you ll get the immutable Bitmap
            Bitmap copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(config, true);
            // scan through all pixels
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                    // get pixel color
                    pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                    if (x == 400 && y == 200) {
                        copyBitmap.setPixel(x, y,
                                Color.argb(0xFF, Color.red(pixel), 0, 0));
                    } else {
                        copyBitmap.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(copyBitmap);
        }
});
```